# Transforming a list of Long into a Map with long item as the key and list of String as the value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a person

```
class Person{
  private Long id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  //with getters and setters
}
```

I have a following method that receives a person's id and returns a list of tags that are associated with the person

```
public List<String> getTags(Long personId){
 /*ExampleImplementation*/
   someCollection.stream()
     .filter(Objects::nonNull)
     .map(SomeType::someMethod)
     .filter(Objects:nonNull)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I am building a method in order to get a map of all the personIds and the list of tags associated with the personId.

```
public Map<Long, List<String>>getPersonTags(List<Long> personIds){
  return personIds.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            (personId) -> personId,
            Collectors.mapping(this::getTags, Collectors.toList())));
}
```

But `getPersonTags()` is returning a `Map<Long, List<List<String>>>` but I expect a `Map<Long, List<String>>` What should I change to get my expected return type.

Comment: Why doesn't `getTags()` use `personId`?

Comment: Are your `personIds` distinct? If so, just use `Collectors.toMap()`.

Comment: @shmosel Editing my comment: No personIds are not unique in the collection. That's the reason I tried with Collection.groupingBy since there was a "Duplicate Key" error

Answer (score 1):

If `personIds` contains distinct values, you don't need to use `groupingBy()`. Use `toMap()` instead:

```
return personIds.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), this::getTags));
```

Comment: Have edited my comment to your question: No personIds are not unique in the collection that I have. That's the reason I had to try with Collection.groupingBy since there was a "Duplicate Key" error. Sorry for the wrong info earlier